# Terminal command to control the standard Music/Video Player(Play/Stop/Next..)

Tags: xmodmap, music-player

After googling for a while now I'm unable(-.-) to find a solution for this:

I want to tell my standard(as noted in settings) `music/video player` to `play/stop/next` via terminal. But with a `global command` and not `/usr/bin/banshee --next` command for example.

Here is what I found till now: X86AudioNext(keyboard keys), xmodmap(organisation of keyboard keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general answer to your question, since music players can implement whatever they want.

However, the default players for Ubuntu all implement the mpris2 interface (if they are integrated into the soundmenu). Therefore they can be controlled via the command line.

One possible script to use is here: [pympris](https://bitbucket.org/whitelynx/pymprisr/overview).

You can run it like this:

> mpris2-remote.py play
>
> mpris2-remote.py stop
>
> mpris2-remote.py next

If you prefer something more basic, you can look at the mpris2 definition [here](http://www.mpris.org/2.1/spec/).

Alternatively you can emulate the gnome multimedia keys as you already wrote in your question.

Comment: Thank you this should solve my problem. I forgot to say that it should run on a fresh Ubuntu install. So i will focus on emulating the gnome keys. If i get it i will post the result here. And if i dont get it i will use the mpris2-remote packge, its sound pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very old but it seems to be getting a lot of views so I will share another solution that worked for me.

Install the `playerctl` program. It also provides the means to control the player via MPRIS but is available from the Ubuntu repositories.

```
playerctl --help
Usage:
  playerctl [OPTION…] COMMAND - Controller for media players

  For players supporting the MPRIS D-Bus specification

Help Options:
  -h, --help                     Show help options

Application Options:
  -p, --player=NAME              A comma separated list of names of players to control (default: the first available player)
  -a, --all-players              Select all available players to be controlled
  -i, --ignore-player=IGNORE     A comma separated list of names of players to ignore.
  -f, --format                   A format string for printing properties and metadata
  -F, --follow                   Block and append the query to output when it changes for the most recently updated player.
  -l, --list-all                 List the names of running players that can be controlled
  -v, --version                  Print version information

Available Commands:
  play                    Command the player to play
  pause                   Command the player to pause
  play-pause              Command the player to toggle between play/pause
  stop                    Command the player to stop
  next                    Command the player to skip to the next track
  previous                Command the player to skip to the previous track
  position [OFFSET][+/-]  Command the player to go to the position or seek forward/backward OFFSET in seconds
  volume [LEVEL][+/-]     Print or set the volume to LEVEL from 0.0 to 1.0
  status                  Get the play status of the player
  metadata [KEY...]       Print metadata information for the current track. If KEY is passed,
                          print only those values. KEY may be artist,title, album, or any key found in the metadata.
  open [URI]              Command for the player to open given URI.
                          URI can be either file path or remote URL.
  loop [STATUS]           Print or set the loop status.
                          Can be "None", "Track", or "Playlist".
  shuffle [STATUS]        Print or set the shuffle status.
                          Can be "On" or "Off".
```